# Temporary objects type and life time

Tags: c++, c++11

In the project I work I saw code very similary with next one:

```
std::string str = (std::string() += "some string") += "some other string";
```

For obvious reasons I can't reproduce the original code, but I can say it uses custom `String` and `operator<<` that has same behavior as `operator+=` for `std::string`.

I feel something is very wrong here, beside the creation/destruction of unnecessary temporary objects, but I don't know exactly what.

Are the temporary objects `const`? Is yes, how does this code compile(VS2010) because `operator +=` mutates the object? Can you please explain what are the problems here?

Comment: This looks to me like a misguided attempt to prevent the "excess" temporary objects associated with a string of `operator+`.

Comment: The main thing that's wrong here is that it is extremely ugly, unidiomatic and unintuitive code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary objects are not `const`; they are rvalues.  That means they can bind to a const reference (C++03) or a (const or non-const) rvalue reference (C++11).

In addition, you can call non-const member functions on temporaries, *including* member operators; this is presumably what is happening in this case.  Calling non-const member operators is dangerous as it can lead to leaking dangling references, but in this case you're OK as there are no references persisting outside the expression.

In C++11 we have rvalue references, so the expression can be rewritten more clearly and more safely as:

```
std::string str = std::string() + "some string" + "some other string";
```

The content of the `string` temporary is reused by the free `operator+` via a move constructor; temporaries are left in a moved-from state.

Answer (score 2):

```
(std::string() += "some string") += "some other string";
```

can be broke into

```
temp1(std::string());
temp1 += "some string"
temp1 += "some other string";
```

The parenthesis define the precedence over both += operations. It does not define a scope, so temp1 is not destroyed by any means when this statement is executed.

On the other side the C++ Standard guaranties that both string literals have the lifetime of the program.

Thus, there is a minimal amount of temporary object on this code sample.

It can go for an arbitrary amount of literals

```
 std:string str =  ((((((std::string() += "a") += "b") += "c") += "d") += "e") += "f");
```

Comment: In your sample there is one temporary object. This is more than 0. Considering the move semantics, this is not a big overhead...

Comment: yes that's the point. Only one temporary object will be created in this line, no matters how much chaining you do

Answer (score 1):

To make the lifetime point clearer, the standard says (12.2):

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

And (1.9):

> A full-expression is an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression.

In this case this would (to my best knowledge) be the call to `std::string`s move constructor (which you technically do with the `=` initialization) with `(std::string() += "some string") += "some other string"`. So, put simply, the lifetime of a temporary ends at the `;`, which means you are safe here.